# Android record all events

Tags: android, robotium, recorder

I would like record all users events for test my application.
For example I would the keyboard events, screen tap events etc..

I know Robotium Recorder but I would like understand how it works

Comment: have you seen Activity.dispatchKeyEvent / dispatchTouchEvent etc?

Comment: No, How it works ? Have you any examples please ?

Comment: add Log.d in those methods and see what happens